# How do I find the left end height of an ellipse tilted at the right end?

Tags: conic-sections

Let's say I have a large ellipse on a flat ground as shown in Figure 1 and 2 below. Angles *DBC* and *ABD* are right-angles and the longest radius with respect to the ground, *BD* is perpendicular to line *ABC* and the flat ground. The ellipse is in a stationery state in Figure 1.

Let's imagine I tilt the ellipse at point *C* as shown in Figure 2 until point *C* is **0.3 meters** above the flat ground (or, *CE* is 0.3 meters).

How do I find the length of *AF*? Note that *AF* and *CE* are perpendicular to the flat ground.

[image: Tilted Ellipses]

Comment: Looks tricky but I expect the way to go is to find expressions for the y coordinates of A, C and the lowest point of the ellipse, relative to the centre, for any given rotation angle; subtract the second from the third to find an expression for the height of C above the lowest point (the ground) and solve for this being 0.3. I suspect the trickiest part will be finding the third expression which will involve calculus to minimise y given the equation of the tilted ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Let us rotate the second figure so that $AC$ is horizontal. Now $EF$ is a tangent line to the lower half of the ellipse.

At this point the equation of the ellipse is:

$$\left(\dfrac{x}{30}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{y}{1.5}\right)^2 = 1 $$

And the function for the lower half of it is:

$$y = -1.5\sqrt{1 - \left(\dfrac{x}{30}\right)^2} $$

Recall that the equation of the tangent line to a function $f(x)$ through the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is

$$ y - f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$$

With our curve, the equation of a tangent to the lower half of the ellipse is:

$$y + 1.5\sqrt{1 - \left(\dfrac{x_0}{30}\right)^2} = \dfrac{x_0}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}(x - x_0) $$

or, equivalently (after some algebraic manipulation)

$$y = \left(\dfrac{x_0}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}\right)x -  \left(\dfrac{60^2}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}\right)$$

Now we have to find $x_0$ so that this line is $EF$, i.e. the distance between the line and $C$ is $0.3$.

The distance between a line $y = ax + b$ and a point $(X,Y)$ is

$$\dfrac{|aX-Y + b|}{\sqrt{a^2 +1}} $$

If our axis are the same as the ellipse axis, then our point $C$ has coordinates $(30,0)$ so our distance is

$$\dfrac{\left|\dfrac{30x_0 - 30^2}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}\right|}{\dfrac{\sqrt{600^2 - (20^2 - 1)x_0^2}}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}} = \dfrac{900 - 30x_0}{\sqrt{360000 - 399x_0^2}}$$

We have to find $x_0$ so that this number is $0.3$:

$$0.3 = \dfrac{900 - 30x_0}{\sqrt{360000 - 399x_0^2}} \implies \sqrt{360000 - 399x_0^2} = 3000 - 100x_0 \implies $$
$$360000 - 399x_0^2 = 9000000 - 600000x_0 + 10000x_0^2 \implies $$
$$10399x_0^2 - 600000 x_0 + 8640000 = 0$$

The solutions are

$$x_0 = \dfrac{300000 \pm 1200\sqrt{106}}{10399}$$

Since $x_0 \in [-30,30]$ we only consider the solution with the "minus". This gives us the equation for $EF$.

Now we have to find the tangent line to the ellipse parallel to $CE$. Out of the two that exist, we will select the one closest to $A$. Since that line is perpendicular to $EF$, then the slope of said line is

$$-\dfrac{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_0^2}}{x_0} = -\sqrt{\dfrac{2503+250\sqrt{106}}{72}}$$

So for some $x_1$ we have that

$$\dfrac{x_1}{20\sqrt{30^2 - x_1^2}} = -\sqrt{\dfrac{2503+250\sqrt{106}}{72}}$$

therefore

$$\dfrac{x_1^2}{12000 -400 x_1^2} = \dfrac{2503+250\sqrt{106}}{72} \implies $$
$$ (1001272 + 100000\sqrt{106})x_1^2 = 12000(2503 + 250\sqrt{106})$$

Solving for $x_1$ we get

$$x_1 = -\sqrt{\dfrac{2996170500 - 375000\sqrt{106}}{99747191}}$$

Plugging this into our ellipse equation we get $y_1$:

$$y_1 = -\sqrt{\dfrac{867763014 + 3750\sqrt{106}}{398988764}}$$

Finally, plugging this points into our point-line distance equation we get that the distance needed is:

$$\dfrac{|ax_1 - y_1 + b|}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}}$$

Where 
$$a = \sqrt{\dfrac{72}{2503+250\sqrt{106}}} \qquad b = \dfrac{3600a}{x_0}$$

Numerically, the solution is approximately $13.2781237$ meters.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't imagine which point and the tangent line you're referring to. Can you use my picture and draw it out? Thanks.

Comment: Using angles would be less complicated (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3716551)